# Simple xml-request (GET)

Tags: python, xml, url, request

I got an url and a some header-data - which, so I've been told, are necessary:

```
url = "sample_url"
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

With the sample-url I want to create a GET request and receive xml-data via python but don't know which is currently the best way to do that!

Might someone give me advice or example?

Comment: `GET` doesn't send any content, so you don't need to send the `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using requests library:

```
url = 'sample_url'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'Accept': 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
xml = r.text
```